# FreeRTOS Memory management question - Is tCB and task stack allocated on MCU's stack or heap?

Tags: c, heap-memory, freertos

For heap_1 implementation in FreeRTOS, what is the meaning that the TCB and task stack is stored in microcontroller's RAM? If I look into the code, a statically allocated array is created with the size of configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE macro. This array is allocated on the bss since it is extern ( I saw the map file)

so technically, nothing is stored on the MCU's heap, correct?

henever I read an article on this, it baffles my mind. I think it's the FreeRTOS heap we are talking about. The kernel treats that static array as a heap, but it is really stored on the microcontroller's RAM, data section in particular?

Answer (score 0):

We're talking about where the task's stack gets allocated. Remember, each task needs its own stack to be able to be preempted by the task scheduler.

From https://www.freertos.org/a00125.html

> Each task requires RAM that is used to hold the task state, and used by the task
> as its stack.  If a task is created using xTaskCreate() then the required RAM is automatically
> allocated from the FreeRTOS heap.  If a task is created
> using xTaskCreateStatic() then the RAM is
> provided by the application writer, so it can be statically allocated at compile time.

As I understand this, you can allocate the memory for the task's stack both statically and dynamically (depending on how you create the task). See https://www.freertos.org/xTaskCreateStatic.html

---

`configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE` is a separate concept from the discussion of the task stack. It defines the size of the heap (shared between the tasks), used for dynamic allocation.

Comment: Hi Morten, Thank for your answer. yes we can use both APIs. What if I use taskCreate(). It mentions dynamic allocation but the array is still a static array. This is what confuses me.

I think the array is static but the way kernel uses it for TCB allocation is dynamic?

Also, I think configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE is related as the task stack as well as the task data for each task is stored on it.

Comment: @MuhammadAli dynamic allocation in this array.

Comment: Hi @0___________. Sorry can you kindly expand this answer? 

The array is statically declared but the task data is allocated dynamically in this static array right? For example, I recently read this article: https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/introduction-to-rtos-solution-to-part-4-memory-management/6d4dfcaa1ff84f57a2098da8e6401d9c#:~:text=When%20you%20create%20a%20task,priority%20and%20local%20stack%20pointer.

It says that the Heap was used, I see some others saying the same thing, and some say that the array is on the stack itself

Comment: @MuhammadAli An MCU typically only has internal SRAM. Heap and stack-memory is both allocated from the same piece of memory, but in different "parts"/segments of the memory range. So both the dynamic and statically allocated memory comes from the same place. The RTOS can use a piece of this memory to allocate dynamically from. When you spawn a task, you need a chunk of memory to use as the task's stack, no matter if this memory is allocated dynamically or statically :)

Comment: Spot on @MortenJensen. I am aware of that too. So when I call xTaskCreate() simply, is that memory allocated statically or dynamically of the SRAM? Did it use the stack or heap? I think neither. 
I could see in the map file that heap_1.o took 16KB from the RAM. I saw the array allocated to the bss symbol. which means it is stored on the RAM's bss.

It's always RAM that I know. Just need to know which area of the RAM

Comment: @MuhammadAli According to the docs (cited in my answer), `xTaskCreate` allocates the task's stack from the heap, while `xTaskCreateStatic` allows the programmer to choose. `If a task is created using xTaskCreate() then the required RAM is automatically allocated from the FreeRTOS heap. If a task is created using xTaskCreateStatic() then the RAM is provided by the application writer, so it can be statically allocated at compile time.`

Comment: @MortenJensen yes. However, I do not see the same reflection in my map file which is strange. Infact my heap size is only 256 bytes whereas the total FreeRTOS heap allocated is 16 KB, which went straight to .bss.

Answer (score 0):

> so technically, nothing is stored on the MCU's heap, correct?

No, MCU does not know anything about the heap. Heap is an abstract memory area which can be used by the dynamic allocation functions.

> henever I read an article on this, it baffles my mind. I think it's
> the FreeRTOS heap we are talking about. The kernel treats that static
> array as a heap, but it is really stored on the microcontroller's RAM,
> data section in particular?

Yes it is a big array to prevent linker from taking this memory for anything else. It does not have to be in any particular section you can place it in any section you like.

> This array is allocated on the bss since it is extern ( I saw the map
> file)

As I wrote it can be in any section you like.

I think you should rather focus learning how to **use** RTOS instead of researching internals. Gain some more knowledge and experience and come back to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am more interested in the internal architecture. I am looking to reduce the size of RAM but want to understand the concept on how the memory is allocated on RAM and Flash.